# Отказано в доступе Process.Start

Tags: c#

```
 Process.Start(Path);
```

> TheBatPortable.exe 170529 01:03:15 | not run (Click_2)
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Отказано в доступе 
>   в System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    в System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    в
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    в
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)

не помогло:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); //создаем новый процесс
processInfo.Verb = "runas"; //в данном случае указываем, что процесс должен быть запущен с правами администратора
processInfo.FileName = Path; //указываем исполняемый файл (программу) для запуска
Process.Start(processInfo); //пытаемся запустить процесс
```

но запускается только если программа в которой это выполняется, запущена от админа

Comment: Ну так проверьте, есть ли доступ

Comment: а как его получить?

Comment: Это вас спросить надо. Прежде всего - что именно содержится в Path.

Comment: путь к TheBatPortable.exe

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Объясните, что вы делаете. Вдруг вы, например, загрузили файл из интернета.

Comment: пытаюсь запустить программу но похоже она требует повышение прав или доступ к папке с ней требует прав.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

помогло добавление в app.manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```